# What do I call an introductory section written by myself (not the author)

Tags: editing, non-fiction, forewords

I am putting together an electronic version of a book written by my grandfather about his service in the middle east in WW1.  The other grandchildren and I have transcribed the text from scanned images.

My question:  I want to add a brief note about the process involved, remarks about how we dealt with unfamiliar idioms he had used, etc.

- What do we call this (it's not a preface, and anyway, he already wrote one of those)?
- is it a foreword?
- should it come before the preface, after the title page?

Comment: If I wanted to know the answer to this question I might visit the website of an online bookseller and have a look at how some of the books available there handle this set of 'problems'. FWIW I think you should probably call it a 'foreword' and that it should precede any preface, but follow the title page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that this would indeed be a foreword. [As per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreword) (emphasis mine):

> A foreword is a (usually short) piece of writing, sometimes placed at the beginning of a book or other piece of literature. **Typically written by someone other than the primary author of the work, it often tells of some interaction between the writer of the foreword and the book's primary author** or the story the book tells. [...]
>
> When written by the author, **the foreword may cover the story of how the book came into being or how the idea for the book was developed**...

This seems to perfectly describe what you're referring to.

As for where it would go, [Wikipedia's article on prefaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preface) states that the foreword should come first (again, emphasis mine):

> An introductory essay written by a different person is a foreword **and precedes an author's preface**.